# how to access the LDAP Users with Administrator credential

Tags: c#, .net, ldap

i have to create the user in My Application but before that i need to validate the user in the Active Directory,also validate it with user/password for login,but when i run the below code it gives that server is unavailable.

```
try {

  LdapConnection connection = new LdapConnection(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ADDomain"]);

  Console.WriteLine("Enter LDAP User Name:");
  string LDAPUser = Console.ReadLine();
  Console.WriteLine("Enter LDAP User Password:");
  string LDAPPass = Console.ReadLine();

  NetworkCredential credential = new NetworkCredential(LDAPUser, LDAPPass);
  connection.Credential = credential;
  connection.Bind();
  Console.WriteLine("logged in");
  string c = Console.ReadLine();

} catch (LdapException lexc) {
  String error = lexc.ServerErrorMessage;
  Console.WriteLine(lexc);
  string ads = Console.ReadLine();
} catch (Exception exc) {
  Console.WriteLine(exc);
  string ss = Console.ReadLine();
}
string s = Console.ReadLine();
```

ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ADDomain"] is ldap path "ldap://IP:389/ou=Service Accounts,DC=DEVDD,DC=ABC,DC=Local?sAMAccountName?sub"

the error Server is not available occured on .bind() line.

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation for the `LdapConnnection` constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.protocols.ldapconnection.-ctor?view=netframework-4.8#System_DirectoryServices_Protocols_LdapConnection__ctor_System_String_) says that the parameter should be:

> A string specifying the server which can be a domain name, LDAP server name or dotted strings representing the IP address of the LDAP server. Optionally, this parameter may also include a port number, separated from the right end of the string by a colon (:).

So it should be *just the server*, not an LDAP path. You can change your `ADDomain` to just be the server IP (or domain DNS name). Port 389 is the default, so you don't need to include the port unless it's not 389.